# Combining ordinal and categorical (one-hot encoded) variables in one model

Tags: feature-engineering, categorical-encoding

I have a dataset with combination of ordinal and categorical (strictly discrete) variables. I want to predict another discrete variable (can be probably restricted to binary, but better, ordinal in general). Lets not be bounded to some specific model, lets say some canonical from `scikit-learn`, like tree-based methods or logistic regression.

I encoded ordinal variables to a natural scale, so they are just integers (with relatively low max size 50, but usually much less, like 0-9). Categorical variables are one-hot encoded (in `pandas` something like `pd.get_dummies`).

I am wondering if I can use this mixed-type dataset as an input in a model. I would say that it matters on algorithm used. E.g. logistic regression could be able to handle this mixed dataset well - there will be either 0 or 1 before $\alpha_i$-ith coefficient in case of categorical, and natural number in front of $\alpha_j$-jth in case of ordinal feature. In case of decision trees it basically doesn't matter (they just could have less splits on ordinals).

The reason why I don't want to encode ordinal variables is losing some information (and increasing dimension). I am not asking if the model performs better - that is of course better to try and evaluate. I am just asking if there is some standard approach to this and if my reasoning is correct or somehow fundamentally incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct, and you could make both mentioned variants work. Some things I'd like to point out in short:

- Think about normalizing the data you obtain from whichever encoding you use. This will have different impact on different models (e.g. more impact on logistic regression than tree based models).
- For the standard approach: there are multiple possibilities used out there. As you pointed out, e.g. tree based models can naturally deal with such data, and both categorial and one-hot encoded variables are actually used with it (see e.g. [Applied Predictive Modeling by Max Kuhn and Kjell Johnson](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/)). But if you are dealing with other models, one-hot encoding ore similar might become necessary, as the model might infer different/wrong information from such features otherwise.
- If you happen to have many features, think about employing features selection first (e.g. feature filters, feature wrappers). You could also use such after one-hot encoding variables.

Comment: Thanks. Normalizing and feature selections steps are already included in my flow.